# Elegant way of initialization of List<List<Coordinate>> in C#

Tags: c#, c++, list, populate

I want to check the win on tic-tac-toe on 3x3 2D matrix in C#. I have the following structure:

```
public struct GridCoordinates {
    public int row;
    public int column;
}
```

In order to check all rows, cols and diagonals of the board I could do the following. I could create a pre-calculated `List<List<GridCoordinates>>` where the inner list is collection of 3 coordinates each one representing either a row, col or a diagonal. But when I think how long the initialization of that `List<List<GridCoordinates>>` will be using `new`s, I start to think that in C# there should be a better way. Please advice how to elegantly populate that pre-calculated coordinates.

My BG come from C++ where I could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> using namespace std;

struct GridCoordinates {
    int i;
    int j; 
 };

vector<vector<GridCoordinates>> vec{
    {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0, 2}}
    };

int main() {   std::cout << vec[0][2].j; }
```

Elegant, right?

Comment: Unless your game is going to change board size mid-game, there's no reason to use a `List` here as opposed to a multidimensional array (`new GridCoordinates[,] { ... }` or even `new (int row, int column)[,] { ... }`, taking advantage of tuples).

Comment: A nested List declaration is only slightly longer - avoiding this seems to be a bad reason for looking for something less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a two-dimensional array of (X,Y) tuples as a field in the class like so:

```
static readonly (int X, int Y)[,] winningLines =
{
    {(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)},
    {(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)},
    {(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)},
    {(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)},
    {(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)},
    {(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)},
    {(2, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)},
    {(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)}
};
```

This makes it fairly succinct to declare the array. However, accessing it is still fairly verbose, for example:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(isWinFor('X')); // false
            Console.WriteLine(isWinFor('O')); // false

            board[0, 0] = 'X';
            board[1, 1] = 'X';
            board[2, 2] = 'X';

            Console.WriteLine(isWinFor('X')); // true
            Console.WriteLine(isWinFor('O')); // false
        }

        static bool isWinFor(char player)
        {
            for (int line = 0; line < winningLines.GetUpperBound(0); ++line)
            {
                bool won = true;

                for (int coord = 0; coord < 3; ++coord)
                {
                    var p = winningLines[line, coord];

                    if (board[p.X, p.Y] != player)
                        won = false;
                }

                if (won)
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        static readonly char[,] board = new char[3,3];

        static readonly (int X, int Y)[,] winningLines =
        {
            {(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2)},
            {(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2)},
            {(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0)},
            {(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 1)},
            {(0, 2), (1, 2), (2, 2)},
            {(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)},
            {(2, 0), (1, 2), (2, 2)},
            {(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 0)}
        };
    }
}
```

(NOTE: Tuple support requires c#7.0 or later.)

Answer (score 0):

The struct should be GridCoordinate (singular) (I believe in these things),

Here is what I would do  to keep it clean

Have a class called Coordinate

```
public class Coordinate
{
     int row;
     int column;
     bool status;
}
```

have a row of coordinates

```
public class Row
{
     int length;
     List<Coordinate> coOrds;
}
```

finally have a class called Grid

```
public class Grid    
{
     int cols;
     int rows;    
     List<Row> rows;
}
```

now add rows based on the cols and rows you need dynamically.

this way it is expandable and clean..

Comment: It's C#, I gave only abstract implementation . Changed indentation properly. My bad :)

Comment: @AndriyTylychko, Thank you for pointing out, I have corrected the same